# How to change Drawable color dynamically for buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable, android-color

I have drawable xml up.xml as in the following code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid
                android:color="@color/green" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and I have this drawable attached to a button as follows

```
   <Button android:id="@+id/bill_amount_up"
   android:layout_width="30dp"
   android:layout_height="30dp"
   android:background="@drawable/up"
     />
```

I'm trying to change the color of the solid android:color="@color/green" in the up.xml file dynamically in my code. I tried the following, but it didn't work.

```
 ((GradientDrawable)billAmountUp.getBackground()).setColor(color);
```

I get the following error
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22001541/android-shape-xml-rotated-drawable-change-color-programmatically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this my friend

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.button ); 
ColorFilter filter = new LightingColorFilter( Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK);
myIcon.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Kotlin code

```
    val myIcon =ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@LoginActivity,R.drawable.button)
    val filter: ColorFilter = LightingColorFilter(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK)
    myIcon.colorFilter = filter
```

Comment: @Parthan_akon happy to help you